# Multiple relative Imports in python 3.5

Tags: python

This structure is just an example

```
pkg\
  test\
    __init__.py
    test.py
  __init__.py
  source.py
  another_source.py
```

another_source.py

```
class Bar():
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "bar"
```

source.py

```
from another_source import Bar
class Foo():
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "foo"
    b = Bar()
```

test.py

```
from ..source import Foo

if __name__== "__main__":
    f = Foo()
    print(f.name)
```

Now I want to run test.py. 
As it has been accepted as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) I have to go above my current package and run

```
python -m pkg.test.test
```

But this does not work and python gives me a traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "-\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "~\test\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..source import Foo
  File "~\source.py", line 1, in <module>
    from another_source import Bar
ImportError: No module named 'another_source'
```

If I remove all the another_source-stuff it will work, but that is not a solution.

Now is there a sane way to import classes from places that are one directory above me?

Comment: `from pkg.source import Foo` if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkg.source` is trying to import things from the `pkg.another_source` module as if it were top-level. That import needs to be corrected:

```
from .another_source import Bar
# or
from pkg.another_source import another_source
```

Comment: But then my main-script imports ( same directory as source.py ) fail.

Comment: @Nozdrum: Then you're probably not being consistent about where the package hierarchy starts when you run these programs. You need to run those as `python -m pkg.whatever` from above the `pkg` directory too, or you need to put in a bit of boilerplate to fix `__package__` and `sys.path` that's too much to explain here (but reading [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) would be a good start).

Comment: It works if I run my main.py the same way I run my test.py. But it really doesn't make any sense to me as to why it works. The -m switch says it there to "run library module as a script", but I am not running any library modules. I am running a "main"-script, just as my test.py is not a library, but a test-case.

Comment: @Nozdrum: If you put them in the `pkg` directory, they're submodules of the `pkg` package. If you don't want them to be part of the package, you should put them somewhere else, or perhaps having `pkg` actually be a package isn't really what you need.